# How to convert a long binary string to an integer in python? (base > 36)

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bitwise-and

I have a bit string of length 128 and want to perform Bitwise AND on it. To do that, I want to first convert the bit string into a integer.

```
int("00000010000....0000000",128)
```

However, python gives an error:

```
ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36
```

My question is how can I convert a long bit string into an integer in Python? Or is there any other way that I can do Bitwise AND without converting the bit string into an integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int()` takes a literal and base. What you are looking to do is convert the literal that is in base 2. The literal can be of any length:

```
int("00000010000....0000000", 2)
```

The python documentation for `int()` can be found here: [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 0):

If u want to create your function use functool.partial

> from functool import partial
>
> base2int= partial(int(), 2)